# How to provide a path to start with to Android's built-in file selector?

Tags: android, file, android-intent, built-in, filepicker

I open Android's built-in file selector using the following code:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
myIntent.setType("text/*");
myIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 100);
```

The file selector opens up fine but it always starts with the recent files list.

Is there any way to provide a directory to start with?